# Broken view after expanding a snippet

Tags: bug, design, stack-snippets

Find a post with Stack Snippet (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) and go for "Expand snippet", for example [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315753/350567).

I got this strange view on Chrome 70 (Windows 10):

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're expecting and what you consider strange?  I do see a visual defect on MSE with the blue header not getting hidden, but I believe it is otherwise behaving as expected.

Comment: @BrianNickel Not sure what it's supposed to look like, but at least a full-width snipoet block overlapping the site logo isn't something well-designed.

Answer (score 4):

I think I may have found the source of the problem:
In https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Js/full-anon.en.js, the statement
`e(".topbar, .container, .top-bar, #footer").hide()` should be
`e(".topbar, .container, .top-bar, #footer, .js-dismissable-hero, .site-header").hide()`

When a post has a snippet, some pieces of the site are not hidden when the snippet is expanded. The header for Meta StackExchange and banners (e.g. welcome or announcements) on StackOverflow and Meta SE (and possibly other sites) are not hidden. This causes the expanded snippet UI to be hard to understand in some cases. See pictures below.

This bug has been reproduced in the following browsers: (Windows 10)

- Chrome 76
- Edge 18
- Firefox 69
- IE 11

The following pictures were from this post:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/279419.
(click thumbnails to view a larger image)

#### Chrome 76

[image: Bug on Chrome 76]

#### Edge 18

[image: Bug on Edge 18]

#### Firefox 69

[image: Bug on Firefox 69]

#### IE 11

[image: Bug on IE 11]

Comment: Happens on my Mac with Firefox 69, too (assuming you are on Windows because a. most people are and b. you have Internet Explorer as an example).